# ¿Por qué Xampp mantiene la misma versión de php?

Tags: php, xampp

estoy en busca de su ayuda para resolver un problema con la versión de PHP que se ejecuta en mi Xampp, actualmente tiene la versión 7.4.18 y la quiero actualizar a la más reciente que a la fecha es la 8.2, intenté con los tutoriales que recomiendan descargar directo de php.org la versión más reciente, cuidando las extensiones, para mi caso **VS16 de x64**, intenté desinstalando Xampp y volviendo a instalar descargándolo nuevamente de la página oficial, terminando ejecuté el cmd y me percaté que me arroja la version 7 de PHP... revisé **phpinfo** y ahí si se muestra con que la verisón que tiene instalado es la 8.2 al igual que al ejecutar el shell del panel de xampp

¿en donde debo realizar los cambios para que mi cmd y la versión de xampp sea el mismo?

Comment: La última versión de Xampp a la fecha trae PHP 8.2.0. ¿Tienes alguna ruta de otro PHP agregado a PATH de las [variables de entorno](https://www.google.com/search?q=variables+entorno+path)?

Comment: Tengo 2 y ambas apuntan a **C:\xampp\php** y **C:\xampp\php\php.exe**